# How to I get the values of the keys in this javascript object inside the arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

I need the value for the key country_code and language_code.

I have tried

```
sourceLanguageArray[0].$.country_code;
sourceLanguageArray[0].$.language_code;
```

I get the error:

```
console.log(sourceLanguageArray[0].$.country_code);
            ^
ReferenceError: sourceLanguageArray is not defined
```

This is how the code and console logs of the data structure looks like:

```
source_language (includes country_code and language_code)
const sourceLanguageArray = _.map(ontomlClass, 'source_language');

console.log(sourceLanguageArray);
// => [ [ { '$': [Object] } ], [ { '$': [Object] } ],[ { '$': [Object] } ] ]
// => [ { '$': [Object] } ]

console.log(sourceLanguageArray[0]);
// => [ { '$': { country_code: 'US', language_code: 'en' } } ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var sourceLanguageArray = [[ { '$': { country_code: 'US', language_code: 'en' } } ]];

console.log("sourceLanguageArray[0]:", sourceLanguageArray[0]);

console.log("country code:", sourceLanguageArray[0][0].$.country_code);
console.log("language code:", sourceLanguageArray[0][0].$.language_code);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sourceLanguageArray.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item[0]['$'][country_code]);
    console.log(item[0]['$'][language_code]);
})
```